# How to design circular Girdview kind User Interface in android

Tags: android-layout, android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am working on an application where I want to design user interface as below. I want to perform the click action on the any of these get clicked. Example I clicked on the "family" so i want to redirect the user to some page according to the selection from here. I want to design it in such a way (Like a gridview ) so that I can add more option into it when needed. The images which are being display will be fetched from any server.. I dont want to design it using image view . I would love to prefer any gridview kind of library.

[image: User interface in such a way which should work on click on each image clicked]

Comment: try this https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

Comment: Thanks @deniz.. I will check it out and let you know. I think it will be a good link for start..thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this awesome [circular image](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) library hope it helps.

Note:

**It just provides the circular Imageview you have to write the code for GridView I hope You know how to customized gridview**

Comment: @james..Thanks for giving the link.. i am already aware with the designing of the circular imageview.Actually the thing i am looking for is a library for such kind of gridview or custom gridview tutorial link for the same..

Answer (score 1):

There is one good library created by **dmitry-zaitsev** on Github. Please check **[CircleLayout](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout)**

[image]